# How to change CAGradientLayer.locations property animated?

Tags: ios, animation, cagradientlayer

How to change CAGradientLayer.locations property animated?

I want to make some effect like a breath light, I tried change the locations preperty of CAGradientLayer in transaction but nothing happened.

So what should I do ? Is there any better way?